Surface Laptop 3 Crashes On Keyboard Input After Screen Blank
Running 24.04.1, laptop boots fine, I can login, everything works perfectly until the laptop is left idle and the screen eventually shuts off.  At that point I can still ssh in and everything is fine, but the moment I press any key on the keyboard it crashes.
Here is the output of lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Processor Power and Thermal Controller (rev 03)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:16.4 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 34e4 (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2c Controller #4 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5021-E21 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less) (rev 01)

